# [DatabaseDesign][Android] Relationship among Player, Game and Performance/Stats Tables

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, uml

A basketball player (Class/Model Player) played a game (Class/Model Game) with a specific Performance/Stats (Class/Model Performance).
Question1:
How to design the database(considering a lifelong basketball player with many many games, and thus performance, as the time goes on)?
In other word, how to relate performance table (suppose there is only ONE big whole performance tables for the moment) to the player table (or player UUID for one specific table) and game tables
Question2:
There are many performance/stats items that can and need to be kept accounts of, such as 3pt shots, 2pt shots, free throws, rebounds, blocks, turnovers, etc.
 Considering a life-long basketball player, should I put every item of performance/stats into a big whole table(might be easier to relate performance table to other tables), or each item in its own separate table(might be easier for career stats)?
What's the advantage and disadvantage of those two extremes?

Question3:
How to save date and time effectively in SQLite?
What specific form and type is recommended?

Comment: The player and the game join in an event, which would be called a match. Each match has one set of statistics. I would make a table containing the matches with the statistics.

Comment: I'd recommend to split these questions into single ones (esp. the 3rd).